# Auth - share the same authenticated user between session and token based auth

Tags: laravel, api, session, authentication, token

I'm looking to implement an auth systeme *- working with laravel 5.5 ( php )*, this is my situation:

```
myApp
    |--> administration (web auth) -no problem i will use the session based auth-
    |
    |--> users have two parts
                |-->first part where there are forms, listing ...
                |-->api part (client space built with react)
```

My main concern is how to share (in a secure and best way) the auth user (same one) between the web part and api one?

what options do i have ?

> If y need more clarification plz do not hesitate to ask, Any help is **appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

You can with for JWT Authentication. It is a token based authentication useful for both web and API's.

You can find more at https://jwt.io/introduction/

&

Also the following links may help you 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport